# Using grep to find uncommented literal integers

Tags: regex, bash, grep, fortran, comments

### What Patterns Do I Want to Match?

I want to find literal constant integers (e.g. 4, 8, 15), but not if they are within a comment (e.g. !4) or part of a variable name (e.g. myvar4).  The language of the file that I'm grepping is Fortran, so the comment symbol is "!".  Here is a file named "MWE.f":

```fortran
j = j + 1      ! <-- match this
!j = j + 1     ! <-- do NOT match this
j1 = j1 + j2   ! <-- do NOT match this
```

### What Have I Tried?

The command `egrep ^[^\!]*[0-9] MWE.f` matches the first line as intended, but it also matches the third line.  So, I tried adding word boundaries with `egrep ^[^\!]*<[0-9]> MWE.f`, but this command throws the following error:

```
-bash: [0-9]: No such file or directory
```

I assume this means that "<" is being interpreted as "pipe input from the file to the right", so I tried escaping the boundary characters with `egrep ^[^\!]*\<[0-9]\> MWE.f`.  Unfortunately, this command does not match any of the lines.

Thanks in advance for your help!

### Appendix: Why Am I Doing This?

To avoid numerical problems in the code, I want to specify the type of each literal constant.  To keep it simple, I've used integers in this example.  Once I get integers figured out, I'm going to extend this to floating point types.  Then I should be able to find any single precision (4 byte) reals and change them to double precision (8 byte) reals.

Comment: Would you want to match the integer literal `1_a`, for example?

Comment: aside from the actual question, it is pointless to clutter the code by specifying  type for small integer literals.  You only need to worry about numbers > 2^31 , and products that could lead to such  large numbers.  If you do this wholesale take care with how you handle literals that appear as function arguments

Comment: @agentp  I was only using small numbers to keep the example simple.  In practice, I'm applying this to real numbers.  I was able to use a parameterized type and the IMPORT keyword to get it to work with function arguments.

Comment: @francescalus  No, I want to ignore anything with a trailing _a (or similar).  I'm assuming that anything like that has already been identified and changed to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your issue is simply a lack of quotes around your pattern:

```
grep -E '^[^!]*\<[0-9]+\>' file
```

works fine for me, matching the first of your three lines. You can also remove the backslash escaping the `!`, as there is no longer any risk that it will be interpreted by the shell as a history expansion. I also added a `+` so that multi-digit constants are matched.

As a general rule, quote your string literals with single quotes to avoid them being interpreted by the shell.

By the way, `grep -E` is specified by POSIX and should be used instead of `egrep`, which is deprecated.